# Unsupported Media Type (415) When Adding WCF Service in VS2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wcf-client

I have a solution with an MVC website and a Console App. The website is hosting 2 WCF services and whenever I try to add a reference to either one in the console app, I get the following error:

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://blah:57997/Service/DWBusinessService.svc'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   `http://blah:57997/Service/DWBusinessService.svc`.  The
>   client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server
>   returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type. If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

Both the website and the console app build fine.

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

edit to say: I'm sure which information is pertinent to this question - feel free to request more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops - Found the issue which is different to other examples I have seen on Google. For some reason I had commented out this block in my website (WCF host) web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Putting that back in and I'm back in business.